# Even function I don't think is even

Tags: geometry, functions

My professor provided the following function:

[image]

which he says is even with a period of $2\pi$.

I get what he means, it's supposed to be a sawtooth-like function. But is this really even? In a function like that, every single line portion would be a different line, right? This function is just going to keep going further and further away, naturally, as we move from $(0,0)$.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: The function is defined on (0,pi) and has period 2pi. To impose that it is even is a way of defining it completely.

Comment: Oh, of course. What confused me was that the professor made it look like you needed to prove it was even. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function is even about the line $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$; i.e. about the line $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, if the left hand part of the function is the reflection of the right hand part of the function, then the function is even.

**Or, in other words,** shift the origin of the co-ordinate system to $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ and suitably change the functions according to the shifting of the axes. Then you will find that the function is even i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set of real numbers, and say that $X$ is *symmetric* if $X$ is invariant under reflection in the origin, i.e., if $-x \in X$ if and only if $x \in X$.

Let $X$ be symmetric. A real-valued function defined on $X$ is *even* if $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $X$ in $X$, and is *odd* if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $X$ in $X$.

As Did notes, your function is defined on $[0, \pi]$, an interval that is not symmetric, and does not have length $2\pi$.

Since your professor mentions an even function with period $2\pi$, it's fairly clear from context that you're meant to consider the *even extension* of $f$, defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$ by requiring $f(-x) = f(x)$ for $-\pi \leq x < 0$. (There is also an *odd extension*, defined by requiring $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for $-\pi \leq x < 0$.)

On the guess that you're studying Fourier series, note carefully that a piecewise-$C^{1}$ function $f$ on $[0, \pi]$ has:

- A *cosine series*, the Fourier series of the even extension.
- A *sine series*, the Fourier series of the odd extension.

The function $f$ itself does not have a Fourier series with respect to the standard trigonometric basis because $f$ (as initially defined, on an interval of length $\pi$) is not $2\pi$-periodic.